# Make any app run full-screen

Tags: fullscreen

Is there any systemwide command to make any app run full screen? It seems some apps have this feature, and some don't. Is there any way to force any app to go full screen?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Depending on your security with ubuntu you may or may not need sudo you can always force in terminal.

sudo application-fullscreen

Comment: What is `application-fullscreen` supposed to be?

Comment: That's a bad answer.

Comment: This doesn't work. Did you misformat your question? Maybe it's supposed to be an argument to a certain app which supports it?